# What is `as` in the class assigning?

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried google and looked through the angular document, but I didn't know what I was looking for.

Would someone explain what this "as" is? what did I do wrong in the following code?

I have component A which is used in component B, and a variable is declared in b 'as' A. I try to use the function from A, but an error occurred here because function doesn't exist.

***A.component.ts;***

```
...

getValue ():Array<string> {
 return this.filter( elm => elm.length > 5 );
}

...
```

***B.component.ts;***

```
...

type C = A;

...

public coolArr: C;

printArr(param: any):void{
 coolArr = param as A;
 console.log(coolArr.getValue);
}

...
```

Not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: This is not related to angular. `as` keyword is from typescript. It is used to cast types. Please go through this. Hope [this](https://acdcjunior.github.io/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function:

```
printArr(param: any):void
```

accepts any type. It may be null, an object, an array, anything. (That's why you should not rely on `any` in your typescript code. Always type for proper types.)

```
coolArr = param as A;
```

Here you tell the typescript compiler: That param is actually of type `A`. Treat it as such. Basically, you say you know better than the compiler and say: Trust me, this will be of type `A`. This works during *compile-time*.

The error you now experience is a *run-time* issue. `coolArr` might still by an anyval, and hence your followup expectation won't work.

Comment: How can I extend A onto B on the param like what I have I intended?

Comment: @Kim.LBy That's a different question. Ask a new one. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first, though.

Comment: thanks, after I read the doc and reread your comment, it started to click. If I cast my ‘param’ at compiling time, then my method may work. But what I have here is passing thru an array of type any and caste it to type A, which is the same as assuming the variable is of type A and tells the compiler to trust that the ‘param’ is of type A.